# Do resistors heat up with left-over amps?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, dissipation

Apologies in advance if I misunderstand and for my bad explanation.

I have heard that resistors heat up when there are left over amps that are not being used.

If this is the case, why do most home electronics resistors not melt with the massive amps coming from the mains (eg, an appliance
draws 2 amps, but the power socket is rated to provide up to 25)

Or do resistors only heat up when supplied with an incorrect voltage?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Albert Marashi! I don't quite understand your question (what is "left over amps"?). If an appliance draw 2 amps, wouldn't an ammeter connected show that the current through the appliance is 2 amps? Why would the 25 A maximum safe current rating of the outlet have any relevance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand what you are saying.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  A circuit might be rated for 25 A, but the appliance uses only 2 A.  That leaves 23 A left over.   You wonder why those left over amps don't heat things up.

A resistor, an appliance, or anything else, heats up only when current is flowing through it.   Massive amps do not come from the mains.  The mains can supply *up to* 25 A.  In your example, 2 A will be drawn from the mains, and that's it.  There is not 23 A going somewhere else. The resistor or appliance will heat up due to that current, but since the current is limited to 2 A, it won't raise the temperature enough to do damage. The current that a resistor or appliance will draw from the mains is determined by the resistance of the device.  A device with high resistance won't draw much current at all.  The design of the device or appliance takes into account the temperature rise that will occur when current is flowing.  The parts and materials to be used in the construction of the device are chosen, among other things, to be able to easily withstand any expected rise of temperature.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of “leftover amps” is not a standard physics concept. Some clarification in the question would be helpful, but based on your question I assume this is more of a residential wiring safety question.

> why do most home electronics resistors not melt with the massive amps coming from the mains (eg, an appliance draws 2 amps, but the power socket is rated to provide up to 25)

Generally, in residential wiring, you want to limit the circuit breaker size to the smallest feasible value. For example, even if the wiring in the wall can handle 50 amps, if you expect a circuit to be typically used for two 8 amp appliances then you would put in a 20 amp circuit breaker since that is the smallest available breaker that could do it.

Let’s take your example and compare a 25 amp circuit breaker and a 15 amp breaker with a 2 amp appliance operating at 120 V ac.

In normal operation the 2 amp appliance will draw only 2 amps at 120 V regardless of the size of the circuit breaker. By Ohm’s law, $R=V/I$ we can calculate that the resistance of the appliance is 120/2 = 60 ohms. So in normal operation that 60 ohm resistance prevents too much current and therefore limits the power to $P=IV$ which in this case is 120*2 = 240 watts. The appliance is designed to safely dissipate this 240 W of heat.

Electrical safety is not designed for normal operation, it is designed for failure modes. Suppose that electrical device fails with an internal short circuit. Suddenly the resistance of the appliance goes from 60 ohms to 5 ohms. Now, by Ohm’s law the appliance wants to draw 24 amps. So what happens in the 15 A vs 25 A circuit breaker?

The 15 amp circuit breaker trips and momentarily allows 120*15 = 1800 W of power through. However, that power is only allowed momentarily before the circuit is broken. That means that there is little time for the appliance to heat up and cause a fire.

The 25 amp circuit breaker is happy to provide 24 amps of current to the appliance and allows 120*24 = 2880 W of power through. The appliance was only designed to dissipate 240 W of heat safely, so this is more than 10 times the safe amount of heat. The appliance will heat up, and since the circuit breaker does not trip, this heating can continue until something catches on fire.

So the bottom line is that the “unused amps” are dangerous, not in normal operation, but during a short circuit failure. “Unused amps” can be delivered to a failing device and can cause heating and fire.

Answer (score -1):

The heating of the resistors is described by the [Joule heating law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating). It states that the power generated by the current in the resistor is proportional to the square of the current and to the resistance of the resistor. Classically, we understand this as moving electrons collide with lattice atoms and their kinetic energies get turned into heat. Following this reasoning, whenever there are moving electrons (any current) you would have some heating.

In order to melt something you need to first heat it up to the melting point and further supply enough energy to break the bonds between the atoms. One part of the Joule energy goes into heating the device and the other part goes into the environment. All of the devices we use are cleverly made so that their melting point is at around couple of hundreds of degrees Celsius. The devices are also designed so that you can never reach that by Joule heating alone.

As an exercise you could work out how long your burner should be on in order to start melting, if you ignore the cooling from the environment. For that, you would need the melting point and heat capacity of the material, the resistance and current (but typically current = 220V/resistance).